# How to remove a string within a string

Tags: python, string

I am working on something in Python that reads a file and outputs some text.
Let's say that I have this string:

`a = "hello // world"`

Using this function, I would remove the part of the string that comes after the double slash

```
def magic(input):
    return "hello "
```

How could I achieve this simply in python? (Basically I want to remove everything after the //)

Comment: Might be helpful - [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20split#str.split)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are often a lot of trouble, but for certain problems they're perfect.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('//.*', '', 'hello // world')
'hello '
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `find()` to get the position of the double slashes.  Then take a slice of the original string up to that position.

```
a = "hello // world"
pos = a.find("//")
return a[:pos]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 'hello//world'.split('//')[0]
'hello'
>>>
```